# Chromium DevTools Protocol - deleteCookies

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, chromium, chrome-devtools-protocol

I'm trying to use Chromium DevTools protocol, more precisely the Network.deleteCookies method: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-clearBrowserCookies

And it seems like in the description of the method it is written that the url, domain and path parameters are optional parameters, that is, whether to use them or not is optional.

But when I call this method:

```
{"id":3,"method":"Network.deleteCookies","params":{"name":"name_cookie"}}
```

Then comes the error:

```
{"code":-32602,"message":"At least one of the url and domain needs to be specified"}
```

Why is that? Tell me please.

Comment: they are optional to allow specify (an url) xor (domain/path pair)

Comment: do you mean that i must specify either the "url" or the "domain/path pair"?

Comment: Yes. The name doesn't identify a cookie because multiple sites may use the same name.